# How to move the Google Maps Logo to the Bottom Left corner of the Map

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

In Google Maps I need to move the Google logo that is at the Bottom Center.
How can I get this to be located at the Botton Left instead.

I think I need jQuery to do this, but can't figure it out.

```
<div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 17px; z-index: 1000000; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 921px;">
    <a style="position: static; overflow: visible; float: none; display: inline;" target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=53.648789,-8.514405&z=6&t=m&hl=en-GB&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3" title="Click to see this area on Google Maps">
        <div style="width: 52px; height: 20px; cursor: pointer;">
            <img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 52px; height: 20px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google_dark.png" draggable="false">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Hope someone can help with this, please.

Comment: I'm pretty sure their terms of service forbid you tinkering with their logo.

Comment: The logo is covering some markers, so when someone tries to click the marker it opens a new Google maps page instead of the marker.

Comment: Couldn't they just pan the map so that the logo isn't covering the markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this to relocate it:

```
function GoogleLogoControl(controlDiv, map) {
// Set CSS for the control div
var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
controlUI.style.width = '52px';
controlUI.style.height = '20px';
controlUI.title = 'Click to see this area on Google Maps';
controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

// Set CSS for the control image
var controlImage = document.createElement('img');
controlImage.src = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google_dark.png';
controlImage.style.width = '52px';
controlImage.style.height = '20px';
controlUI.appendChild(controlImage);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
window.open('http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=53.648789,-8.327637&z=6&t=m&hl=en-GB&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3')
});
}
```

In the function initialize() I added:

```
// Add Google Logo to Bottom Right Corner as it was remove from Bottom Center using CSS
var googlelogoControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var googlelogoControl = new GoogleLogoControl(googlelogoControlDiv, map);

googlelogoControlDiv.index = 1;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(googlelogoControlDiv);
```

Comment: new GoogleLogoControl ? How to do this in angular?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I'm displaying a nearby places search form and the results in a semi-transparent container that lays over the map. The google logo was partially obscured by this container and, for fear of violating the ToS, I wanted to make it visible by offsetting it by the container's width. Here's what I did:

I targeted the element by its title, since it had no class or anything.

```
$('[title="Click to see this area on Google Maps"]')
```

It's important to note that the element wasn't being found unless I waited for the map to finish loading. I was already using the "tilesloaded" event so I wrote a function named moveGoogleLogo() that executes once that event is fired.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){

    // Move Google logo
    moveGoogleLogo();

});


function moveGoogleLogo(){
    var container = $('#my-overlay-container')
    $('[title="Click to see this area on Google Maps"]')
    .closest('div').css('left', container.outerWidth()+'px');
}
```

I noticed that the element itself was wrapped in a div, so I used closest() to get that div, then added the width of my container as the left value.

And that worked for me! I hope this helps someone else. I realize that if they change the title in later versions, the code would have to be updated but whatever. To me this was a better solution than recreating the element.

**UPDATE:**

My solution above did not work the way I desired since, as the map changed, the logo would re-position itself. What I ended up doing was cloning the element with .clone() and hiding the original. This seems to get the job done.

Comment: Great idea on the cloning, works like a charm. Don't forget to listen to map idle and update the cloned HREF attribute with the original one.